# Reading HttpPost response

Tags: java, android, http

I'm using this code to post a request to a http server:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost( "http://192.168.0.1/test.php" );
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    List< NameValuePair > nameValuePairs = new ArrayList< NameValuePair >( 1 );
    nameValuePairs.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "num", "2" ) );
    post.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( nameValuePairs ) );
    response = client.execute( post );
}
catch( ClientProtocolException e ) {
    ...
}
catch( IOException e ) {
    ...
}
```

The response is nothing more than a simple `String`.  How can I read this response as a `String`?  It doesn't seem like HttpResponse have a method for doing this directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have created this helper method for sending data and special headers by POST method in Android (headers HashMap could be empty if you do not have any custom headers):

```
public static String getStringContent(String uri, String postData, 
        HashMap<String, String> headers) throws Exception {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
        request.setURI(new URI(uri));
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(postData));
        for(Entry<String, String> s : headers.entrySet())
        {
            request.setHeader(s.getKey(), s.getValue());
        }
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8"));
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            throw new Exception(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        while(true )
        {
            s = buf.readLine();
            if(s==null || s.length()==0)
                break;
            sb.append(s);

        }
        buf.close();
        ips.close();
        return sb.toString();

 }
```

Comment: IMHO it is better to check if status ok first if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.SC_OK){// some code }else{//some handling..}

Comment: Don't forget to cover this with try-catch block ;)

Comment: this way does not effectively if the string of the reponse has million/billion character. It's too slow. I've tested

Answer (score 5):

`response.getStatusLine();`// For reading status line

```
org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```