# Retriving website after POST in android

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am using java.net.HttpURLConnection to connect to a website and send some data through a POST command. Now I am trying to find out if there is a way to read/parse the resulting website?

The PHP script I am posting to echo's some infromation on the site after the POST and that is what I want to read.

The only feedback I am able to find is the responseCode and responseMessage through getResponseCode() and getResponseMessage() but that is not really what I am looking for.

Is there any good way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading HttpPost response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361601/reading-httppost-response)

Comment: @mbaird I don't think its a dupe of that one, as the link is for an `HttpPost` rather than an `HttpURLConnection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are doing something like this:

```
HttpURLConnection urlc = null;
DataOutputStream dataout = null;
URL url = new URL(URL_LOGIN_SUBMIT);
urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// set up post
...
dataout = new DataOutputStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
dataout.writeBytes(output);
int responseCode = urlc.getResponseCode();
```

If so, you can add this part:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()),8096);
String response;
while ((response = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(response);
}
...
```

It will just write the output to the `System.out` but it should give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to this question:
[Reading HttpPost response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361601/reading-httppost-response)